# Comparing two dataframe pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes and I have to compare these dfs. if rows in the dfs are same, I should find this row. I have written code but not running correctly.

```
def color(row):

    if (df3_2['dt'].values == df_condition['dt'].values ) & (  df3_2['platform'].values == df_condition['platform'].values) & (  df3_2['network'].values == df_condition['network'].values) & (  df3_2['currency'].values == df_condition['currency'].values) & (  df3_2['cost'].values == df_condition['cost'].values) :
        return "asdas"
    else:
        return "wewq"

df3_2.loc[:, 'demo'] = df3_2.apply(color, axis = 1)
```

Code wrote "asdas" all rows in the dataframe but Dataframe has different columns.

Thanks

Comment: Dataframe has different rows

Comment: What bout joining dataframes with `.merge()` while enabling the merge indicator - https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html#the-merge-indicator ?